# Chrome Table List rendering bug

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-lists, html-table

We are encountering a problem with layout of a styled unordered list inside of a table cell in Google Chrome.  This problem is not happening in Firefox, Safari or Internet Explorer.

The unordered list has styles applied for margin-left and text-indent.  The spans associated with each list item are set to "nowrap" for white-space.

When a list item text span is wide enough to reach the right-hand edge of the cell, it can end up getting displaced down and the text will overlap the cell border.  This problem is easiest to duplicate when changing the Zoom settings inside Chrome, but can also occur unpredictably when first rendering the page or changing the window size.

Here's a link that displays with the HTML that reproduces the problem:
http://www.grandavenue.com/CodeExamples/chrome_table_list_bug.html

Here's an image of the problem:
[Chrome Bug http://www.grandavenue.com/CodeExamples/chrome_td_ul_bug.gif](http://www.grandavenue.com/CodeExamples/chrome_td_ul_bug.gif)

Here an example html page that reproduces this problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Column text to left</td>
        <td align="left">
            <ul style="list-style:disc inside none; margin-left: 2.0em; text-indent: -1.5em;">
                <li><span style="white-space: nowrap">Example text that fits</span></li>
                <li><span style="white-space: nowrap">Example text that doesn't fit</span></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Column text to right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem.  I'm using the table to center a left aligned unordered list. There is only one column and one row.  The table element, nor the TD element have a width defined and yet it choses to not make the table wide enough to prevent the list test from wrapping.  I can specify a static width for the table, but that is bad coding standards and it then centers the text based on the statically defined width, not the actual text width.  Fortunatly, this text isn't dynamic so we can use the statically defined table width.

The problem does not happen in other browser, only Chrome.